# Swift wrongly reading Cloud Code error

Tags: node.js, swift, stripe-payments, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to handle an error from a PFCloud function in Swift with `if error != nil`. Although neither the Cloud Code or Stripe return an error, Swift responds as if there was one.

**Swift**

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("authorize", withParameters: ["customer": self.customerID!, "cost": self.stripePrice, "type": self.stripeDescription) { (success: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    print("Authorizing")
    if error != nil {
        print("authorizeError")
        self.displayAlert("Error", message: "There was an error authorizing your payment. Please try again later.")
    } else {
        if type == 1{
            print("one")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("one", sender: self)
            self.viewTimer.invalidate()
            self.cancelTimer.invalidate()
        } else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("two", sender: self)
            print("two")
            self.viewTimer.invalidate()
            self.cancelTimer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

**Cloud Code (Node.js)**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("authorize", function(request, response){
    var user = request.user;
    stripe.charges.create({ amount: request.params.cost, currency: "cad", customer: request.params.customer, capture: false}).then(function(charge) {
        user.set("chargeID", charge.id);
        return user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log(charge);
        console.log(charge.id);
        response.success(charge); 
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);   
        console.log(charge.id)
        response.error(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to return `charge` in the success callback and charge is null. Change your code as follows:

```
stripe.charges.create({ amount: request.params.cost, currency: "cad", customer: request.params.customer, capture: false}).then(function(charge) {
    user.set("chargeID", charge.id);
    return user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
}).then(function(result) {

    // charge is undefined here.
    console.log(charge);

    // Return something besides charge
    response.success("unused result"); 
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);   
    console.log(charge.id)
    response.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Yes there's no error. A charge is successfully created on Stripe's side.

Comment: Just because a charge is created with Stripe doesn't mean that there's no error. Is the user saved with the proper `chargeId`? What prints to the console when on the line `console.log(charge.id`)? I suspect that `charge.id` is undefined which causes a runtime error and causes `response.success()` to never be executed.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the charge.id lines but it still acts as if there was an error. What else do you suggest I change?

Comment: Can you look in the parse-server logs to see what prints to the console when `console.log(charge)` executes? Also try printing out the error in your Swift code. Instead of `print("authorizeError")` try `print("authorizeError: \(error) ")` to see what the error says.

Comment: @Dups Also, is the user saved with the proper chargeId?

Comment: Thank you once again! Nothing is printed in the log regarding the charge, however, the user is indeed saved with the proper chargeID. I printed what you suggested for authorizeError and the error says `Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.})`

Comment: Rather than returning `charge`, which is most likely undefined since it's out of scope, try returning something else... like this: `response.success("unused response")`

Comment: Thank you so much! I did that, and removed the line console.log(charge) and it now works! Once again, thank you!

Comment: Ok, great! I updated my answer to specifically answer your question. Will you click the check mark to mark it as accepted since it solved your problem?

Comment: Just did it! Thanks again.